# C# search query having NULL references

Tags: c#, search, reference, null, where-clause

This is example similar to my search query, where I have search filter and it should search let's say Customers in foreign table.

```
var query = (from O in dm.Order
                where O.Customer.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                O.Customer.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                select new
                { ... }).ToList();
```

If my customer_ID in Order table is NULL, it will not show those orders.
I need to write a query that should list each records whether I have customer_ID NULL or not. Let's assume that filter is empty string and it needs to show each record.

I tried something like:

```
where O.customer_ID.HasValue ? O.Customer.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter) : (not know what to write here?)
```

I hope You can assume what is all about!

Thanks in advance,
Josip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(O.Customer.Name.ToLower() ?? "").Contains(filter)
```

This should work. But I would not do that. Filter only when filtering is needed.

```
var query = dm.Order;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)){
    query = query.Where(o => o.Customer.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter) 
                           ||o.Customer.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter));
}    
var result = query.Select(o => new {...}).ToList();
```

Comment: Great man, this one works: (O.Customer.Name.ToLower() ?? "").Contains(filter). I'll mark this correct answer ;) ::cheers::